# awk regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I am learning regular expressions in AWK. In AWK `[^ ]` **matches any character not inside**. Now I need to extract those '**a**' which are not part of any word like.

If my input file is

```
a
aa
a+a
.a.a
bac
```

The output will be

```
a+a
.a.a
```

Because *a+a* and *.a.a* are not any words so these lines are printed.
So I did something like this

```
awk '/[^[a-z]]a[^[a-z]]/ {print} input_file'
```

But this is not working. Please Help!

Comment: anyway: `[^[a-z]]` should be `[^a-z]`

Comment: Try `awk '/[^a-z]a[^a-z]/ {print} input_file'` Good luck.

Comment: `a` is a word itself. That is why I thought it should not be in the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
$ awk '/[^[:alpha:]]a|a[^[:alpha:]]/' file
a+a
.a.a
```

depending on how you want `a.` and `.a` in your input file handled.

Comment: Although I have failed to provide a properly documented question you have provided me with the perfect thing I wanted. Thanks for that.